# How to benefit from being able to save my company from a disaster while being laid off cruelly

Tags: professionalism, negotiation, notice-period, legal, layoff

I'm seeking advice on how to handle a high risk opportunity.

My employer recently had to do some layoffs due to changing the underlying technologies used for its products (ie: moving from C to C++, migrating from CVS to GIT, etc). For some stupid reason, they insisted that most of the developers would only be given 3 months notice, but they'd actually have to work it rather than being given 3 months' payout. One of the senior guys that was laid off got a nice 5 month payout, while the rest of us have to work at a job we now hate, and some of my co-workers actually have to train underpaid replacements.

So, everyone is being less than accomodating, griping over verbal language barriers, etc. I am in a very unique situation though. I'm working for about 6 more weeks before I have to turn in my keycard, and have been looking for new work. Due to shoddy IT policies, all the devs have access to the same master password for our data and versioning servers. One IT person (not me, fortunately) decided to do something very mean: he migrated the CVS repo with all our code to GIT, but just the HEAD revision, and there are no copies to be found of the server data from the old CVS server.

The code builds fine with the new GIT server, so we thought everything was fine. Wrong! We checked out the latest copy of a key piece of code (40,000 lines) that our products depend on. Someone (we can't determine whom, since it seems DHCP lease logs and SSH "last" logs don't go far enough back, "admin" user account used to do this), and someone ran it through a parser that:

- Removed ALL comments (these are key, since we have massive lookup tables of register values and bitfields).
- Removed all indentation.
- Swapped all integer literals so they are decimal rather than hex, so the bitfield values aren't apparent.
- Renamed all functions to useless, non-descriptive names.

An example would be:

## Old Code

```
#include <iostream.h>

main()
{
    initDevice();
    int i = 0x8001; // Set MSB and LSB to enable diagnostic mode on older models.
    cout << "Hello World!";
    shutdownDevice();

    return 0;
}
```

## New Code

```
#include <iostream.h>
main()
{
foo_0001();
int i = 32769;
cout << "Hello World!";
foo_0082();
return 0;
}
```

Remember, this was done against about 40,000 lines of code in hundreds of files.

Nobody noticed this because the automated build jobs just kept running fine. Now that things need to be changed, we're pretty much up the creek without a paddle. Me and a few of the other devs know a lot of this code, having written it, but it would be a massive undertaking to correct this mess so that it's at least usable to the point where we can make improvements, support new products with it, etc. Management is furious, and one of the software managers literally threw stuff around his office in a shouting rage when they found out no backups can be found. They have time-based backups, but it seems this change went in several weeks ago, so the oldest backup is this junk code too.

About a half year ago, I was doing remote work from home. The company encourages us to put in extra time via VPN, but it doesn't count as "working time". It's basically a way to get extra work after 5pm out of us for free. There is no policy against using personal computing resources to do work. I have a copy of the pre-SNAFU code base.

The workplace environment isn't great, but pays a LOT more than what I'd make elsewhere. When I'm let go in 6 weeks, it's going to be a pain paying the mortgage and supporting my family, but we'll survive. Is there any way I can capitalize on this? I've though out the following scenarios, and need advice on which route to take. Keep in mind I'm being 100% honest when I state that I was NOT the person who sabotaged the code base:

- Tell the owners I have a spare copy of the code.

  - Maybe they let me keep my job, chances are they won't.
  - I can't really demand they draft a new job offer for me, since it reeks of blackmail/extortion, and they could probably take me to court. They may even think I engineered the sabotage itself.
  - Very high risk, minimal reward.
- Tell the owners I worked so diligently on the project, which I did, that I have most of it memorized, but it would probably take me 2 years to completely recreate.

  - Safest option I can think of.
  - I actually have about 70% of that stuff committed to head, or know how to fix most of this in about 6 months.
  - Helps me pay the bills for a while yet.
- Tell them the same as above, and that I can fix it, but we'd need to negotiate a better pay rate (3x current rate) as an external contractor.

  - Only problem compared to above is it might make them think I'm the saboteur. Not something I want them to think.
- Leave the situation alone, and part ways in 6 weeks.

  - Obviously safest choice.

I don't feel I have any duty to volunteer the code to the company free of charge. I'm not IT support, and I'm not responsible for them not know how to do backup testing. Also, I'm not happy having to help train people that will replace me and my friends. I want to benefit from this situation so I'm not digging into my savings to pay the mortgage while I job hunt, and I don't want to make the owners suspect I caused this and come after me with lawyers, burning up my savings even faster.

Are there any legal routes where I can prosper from this complete disaster?

## Update

It turns out I was mistaken. I never had a copy of the code.

The shouting manager has been sacked, so at least some good came of this.

All of us on notice were called into a meeting room with the CTO and head of the legal team, and they laid out the whole story I just described, and in clear words, said "you little parasitic ****eating ****wads ... we know it was one of you", and demanded us all to sign a written agreement noting that we claimed we had no part in the whole thing, with a legalese-ish clause at the bottom granting them rights to check our personal e-mail to confirm this.

One of the senior developers told everyone not to sign a thing, as there was no way it could benefit us. Nobody signed a thing.

I will simply stay away from this and ride out the next 6 weeks with a smile on my face. Sorry for multiple accounts, trying to protect my privacy.

And no, Jake/Jacob isn't my real name.

## Final Update

First, here's "hello world" encrypted with the password I've used on the past few throwaway e-mail accounts. Pipe it through `openssl enc -d -a -aes-256-cbc` with my account password for this account and the previous two ones for proof.

```
U2FsdGVkX1/Q0Xq+Ium6X5BxoZ7ZhhpLtz7ltU+/WrM=
```

Anyhow, today was insane. Some crazy person on the team found this post and shared it with the team. Of course, the interim software manager got to see it. Well, someone e-mailed management with a demand for payment via bitcoin. No idea if they actually have the code or not. For all we know, it's a troll taking things too far.

Thank you for the sound advice. Staying clear of this. I'm still amazed they haven't just paid off the devs and sent them packing, rather than forcing a group of spiteful devs to train their replacements.

And to address one of the comments: yes, it's a "salary dump". The C developers are fluent in C++ as well, along with CVS, SVN, git, mercurial, etc.

Yes, I thought I had a copy of the code, but I was mistaken. It was a separate project that wasn't altered, not that it matters. I've decided to quit today, and will just zero-wipe my personal HDD at home. Problem solved.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36553/discussion-on-question-by-jacob-how-to-benefit-from-being-able-to-save-my-compan).

Comment: Because OP totally changed question after garnering lots of initial votes.  As it stands the whole things is confusing and useless.

Comment: Well, hopefully the management learned a lesson: When you fire employees there's a reason you escort them from the building that very day and pay them off

Comment: Wow! Bitcoin ransoms, stolen data, OP changing his/her story to potentially cover tracks, hashed data in the question out of super paranoia? This belongs on dailyWTF.

Comment: @DevNull I know right!? I was gripped.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner The way this reads, it sounds like OP could have helped out his/her company, but decided it either wasn't worth the risk or wasn't profitable, and destroyed unintended backups. Hopefully the company learned about the concept of "garden leave" as WayneWerner points out.

Comment: @DevNull `...destroyed unintended backups`, wow, I didn't think of that. I took the statement that they 'didn't have them after all' at face value. Now I can see them, relaxed in an office chair, telling their management as an almost imperceptible twitch moves one corner of their mouth!

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner Yeah, after looking at the edits, it sounds like OP did indeed have the data, and just backtracked after his/her boss found this post. Surprised OP didn't just delete it, but SE tends to prevent deletions once there are high quality answers. Once OP realized that there was no way to benefit from this situation, he/she likely just destroyed all evidence and moved on. Bitcoin ransoms, lol. This is one of the funniest SE:WP questions I've found.

Comment: > "with my account password for this account" — we all know that StackExchange doesn't store passwords, only their hashes, so even if you implied an admin could check it, no, they could not.

Answer (score 69):

This is not a decision you want to spend a long time contemplating: the longer you take to act the more suspicious it will look when you eventually come forward.

I really see three options:

**1. Honesty**

In this situation you are - somewhat - putting yourself at this company's mercy, and also counting on their generosity, which may be ... silly.

You go to your boss and say:

> Listen, I was working from home 8 months ago and have an older version of the program on my personal machine. Here's a USB with it, it's yours.

If this person is a decent human being he will thank you from the bottom of his/her heart, and will offer you a reward. You could potentially ask for one at this point.

> I know you guys are letting us all go, but if you were to offer me a bonus for helping you out I wouldn't refuse it. Have a great day.

You keep your dignity, and you take the moral high ground.

**2. Stay Safe**

If you're dealing with vengeful, irrational, and nasty people, then just ***keep quiet***. If you suspect that any attempt to help them would end in you being accused of plotting against them then you're better off simply leaving in 6 weeks and washing your hands of it all.

However, at that point the company *probably* goes bankrupt, and a lot of people end up losing their jobs. It's not really on you, but you *could* do something about it.

**3. Anonymity**

Put the code on a USB, and type up an anonymous note saying:

> I had this code on a personal laptop due to working on it from home. I don't want to get involved in this situation in any way, so please accept it anonymously. It's a little older, but better than nothing. Good luck!

Then stick them both in an envelope and leave it on a manager's windshield, or in any place where it will be found, but not be traced back to you.

**Conclusion**

I honestly do not think that you can leverage the situation into forcing them to give you a job. If you choose to try and deceive them into letting you "rebuild" the code then sooner or later they will simply come to the conclusion that you sabotaged the project for this very purpose.

Best to do without that particular headache.

Comment: It's possible that company policy might have repercussions to the employee for having taken the work home.  The safest course of action is your number 2 - and just stay out of it.  Items 1 and 3 could be twisted by a good attorney to make it look like the OP actually was the cause of the problem and that they came to their senses only after quite a bit of "damage" was done leaving him open to a lawsuit.

Comment: It's in these situations I like to tell myself "I'll give them as much care as they've given me," and it's then in hindsight the companys' bad for obviously not caring about it's employees.

Comment: I would not put a USB stick on a manager's car.  Advice is OK other than that but doing the USB thing has A LOT of implications/risks.

Comment: @CMosychuk And for combining that attitude with atrocious IT policies. Either you have faith in your employees or you don't, not both.

Comment: Don't use USB or any digital media for path #3. Get the code, go to a far, anonymous print office, print out the whole code (small letters), then anonymously leave the print or mail the code to the company. Take care of security cameras while doing it. Do it so it arrives right next your departure.

Comment: @Mindwin - isn't the printed code next to useless, since the number of man hours necessary to go in and manually enter it would be up in the hundreds? It's a moot point since the OP doesn't have the code, but what's wrong with an electronic version? That it might somehow be tracked?

Comment: For your #3 option, the anonymous route, consider putting in a digital fingerprint so that you can choose to identify yourself at a later time.  I think it'll work if you just put in your PGP public key.  This way, if the managers want to reward you, they can encrypt a message and only the savior (you) can decrypt it.

Comment: @user2023861 - if someone is in a similar situation and decides to go that route they may as well forget about a "reward". Consider that in most circumstances - and especially as far as these people are concerned - whomever comes forward with the code is more likely to be blamed than lauded. In that case would you want to give these people more tools to help them track you?

Comment: @AndreiROM, if I were in the OP's position (and still had the code), I would feel morally obligated to return it.  The code belongs to the company regardless of whether or not I like my manager.  I'm just suggesting that the OP give himself the option to identify himself.  It's not a tool for the manager to track the OP because the manager cannot force the OP or any of his coworkers to decrypt some message.

Comment: @user2023861 - I see what you're saying now. Still, with people that nasty I don't think identifying yourself at _any_ time would be a good idea. Especially after the OP's update it seems to me like they would simply ***love*** to blame someone for it.

Comment: @AndreiROM yes, an USB stick can probably (although might be going into spy territory) be tracked by the serial # and the sale receipt. Also, why make it easy for a company that is laying you off?

Comment: Is there any compelling reason the OP *has* to say it's on a computer at home? What about the little white lie of finding it on their normal company computer, and simply saying they didn't realize it was there until they found it? The OP could even copy it to an obscure location on the machine first, if they really want. (It would be important to preserve file create and modified timestamps in the copying in that case, but this is easily doable. I have 7-Zip configured to preserve create timestamps, for instance.)

Answer (score 48):

## What's your duty? Give it to them - if they want it.

As a paid employee, you have a [fiduciary duty](http://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=724a91e1-94f1-4514-9e30-3749303c7c26) to provide them with this code that belongs to them in the first place.

You should not even begin to consider other alternatives. It's theirs. They pay you. Give it to them.

If they ever find out you withheld it when you knew they wanted it, you could be in a lot of legal trouble. I am not a lawyer. It's probably worth some money to go over your situation with a lawyer to get legal advice.

## Do they really want it?

If you were encouraged to work from home on your own hardware, they should have been polling you and others who may have done the same for if you have copies - if they valued those copies.

Perhaps the copies are too old. Perhaps they have known copies that are even more current that they don't talk about, but that they don't want to use.

## Conclusion: Find out what they want.

There's probably some perverse political stuff going on here that you're not privy to. Be delicate. But find out what they want.

If they want it, give it to them. You'll be the hero. Talk to a lawyer. Good luck.

## Addendum

You didn't mention it, but CVS isn't distributed version control, like git. Maybe they assumed you shouldn't *have* an entire copy of the repo. Definitely time to talk to a lawyer.

## Postscript

> It turns out I was mistaken. I never had a copy of the code.

I wonder why you thought you did. Perhaps you thought CVS worked like distributed systems which you might be familiar with. I am disappointed with your desire to leverage the firm's mismanagement by using something they would already own as a bargaining chip.

Comment: Given the apparent ineptness of management in the fiasco, I wouldn't assume they're aware of but un-interested old copies of the code that might be floating around elsewhere.

Comment: I think you have some good points but I disagree on the employee having any sort of duty to provide a stored copy of something from their home equipment, given it wasn't this employee's job to store the code or back it up.  That side of the law is really enforced if he were to use/sell said code.  If he had done coding outside of work and it is stored outside of work and he would work to get the code back - all true here.  Then he should get paid for that outside work.   How much?  And how would company ever know if he has everything or 20 lines?

Comment: + 1 for your first paragraph. The OP has the duty to act in the best interest of the employer until the moment he leaves on his last day.

Comment: @Anthony I think "act in the best interest of the company" only goes so far... when a company has acted like this? (One side of the story: Laid off, training replacments? Rather prickish...). At this point, it's important to do your job, but ultimately CYA. As others have pointed out, coming forward with a backup (before "I don't have them" edit) puts you in the spotlight of mad people - rightfully or wrongfully.

Comment: Regardless of duty and them being pricks, 10 years from now I'd rather be able to tell the story of how I was able to save the company when disaster struck because I had an old copy somewhere (even though they had already told me I was laid off), than the one about how it was a really bad company I was happy to see go up in flames when they unfairly laid me off. The first one is better for job interviews too, and people will be more likely to think of you whenever they are looking for new people at some completely different company.

Comment: The employer has the duty to act in the best interest of the OP until the moment he leaves on his last day. Does exchanging two words provide some enlightenment @Anthony? OP and employer were in symmetrical exchange (work vs money). Their "duty" was always in symmetry.

Answer (score 28):

The company owns the code. Any attempts of selling them their own code will end in tears.

When you are laid off, all employment contracts that I've had required me to destroy any copies of code, or generally any company documents, that I might have in my possession. And that's what you need to do. If you have been given notice, so you know you are going to be laid of, you might as well start cleaning up what's in your possession right now.

You might watch how well they are doing in the future and get some enjoyment out of it.

PS After your update: So the CTO was making false accusations against almost all developers and insulting them all at the same time. Well, that is going to help. What an idiot. (Why do I say "what an idiot"? If the code was deleted, it doesn't help. But if someone else had a copy at home, as you thought you did, or if the perpetrator had kept a copy, which is not unlikely, there would have been a small chance to get the code back. With his stupid behaviour, he destroyed that possibility). Congratulations for having one senior developer who kept his cool and gave you the correct advise.

Answer (score 22):

In all honesty, I'd say your best option is to leave it alone and leave.

They have acted in bad faith, but don't stoop to their level. It sounds like they are a sinking ship.  Step back and let them drown

Make no mention of the code, EVER.  If you produce it, they'll likely suspect that you were the original vandal and destroyed the code so you could blackmail them with a copy you kept.

Comment: Granted that any attempt at extortion will point the finger of suspicion, but I don't understand why some folks are so sure that handing over what the OP has, even with no request for any reward, would make management assume that the OP was the saboteur. Why do they think the saboteur would do that, when all it does is mitigate the effects of the sabotage? Or is the assumption just on the basis that these managers are so bad that it's in effect "opposite day", and any stupid thing they might think that would harm the OP is in fact what they will think? ;-)

Comment: @Steve You think in pretty much the same as I do in my answer further down this page

Comment: @SteveJessop When tempers are high, people are not rational. Anything the OP does to associate himself with this issue will bring more anger and suspicion.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Have you ever played the party game [Mafia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_%28party_game%29)? (If not -- I recommend it. It's a fun game.) The game only works because, in the absence of real evidence, people are amazingly good at conducting witch hunts on the basis of anything at all. Contradictory rationales are common. (In a party game, of course, there are no stakes, so witch hunts are OK. But this is the OP's real life. He would be ill-advised to blindly assume that his managers are rational agents, when they've already demonstrated that they aren't.)

Comment: @ruakh: it's not so much that I want to assume they're rational, as that I want to know why their irrationality will take this particular form. It might be true that acting to mitigate this problem (or any other problem that arises) will result in being blamed for the problem. But if it's really that bad then the questioner should probably re-consider whether it's really worth the money to work any more than their contractual notice period. Three months seems like a long time to survive without sneezing at the wrong moment and triggering irrational blame...

Comment: @SteveJessop If they're that irrational you probably can't predict what they'd do. In which case it seems like the best course of action is to assume the worst case - they'll blame you and initiate legal action - will happen, and make your decision accordingly.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: maybe, but you could apply that analysis to anything. "Should I make a cup of coffee? Let's assume the worst case, that an angry manager spots me in the hall and in the absence of any other focus of attention decides to blame me for whatever's on his mind at that moment and sue me. Therefore no, I should not make a coffee". But fair enough, "keep quiet and keep your head down" is certainly not the *worst* way to deal with that kind of irrational abuse. I'd add "hand in your notice today".

Comment: @SteveJessop Experience tells me they would blame him.  They are sloppy, devious and unethical from the description the OP gave.  Given that fact, they will assume other people dealing with them would be the same.  I would go so far as to say that this would be a certainty.

Answer (score 17):

For me, there would only be two options.

Do nothing about it and let them stew in their mess. (I'd be very unlikely to do this, but I guess if I was unhappy enough I might) In which case I'd delete their files from my machine.

Secondly, give them the copy of the code.

Everything else you're suggesting is immoral at best and probably illegal if you ever get found out because it's misrepresenting the truth.

If you tried to sell them their own code in whatever convoluted way you have in mind, it would probably be thought that you are the one who sabotaged things in the first place. You're saying you're 100% honest but the whole tone of your question hinges on a lack of ethics and personal honesty.

Answer (score 11):

First of all the company is at fault

- No version control
  Well no saved version
- Let's migrate from C to C++
  OK migrate may be good architectural decision but

  - Hey make a copy
  - Keep a core of C people that know the code and can do C++
- Weak package
  2 month severance and you have to work does not make you an ally
  Make you come to work with logon privileges - that is just STUPID

What you have is valuable to the company and I don't think you have legal or moral obligation to turn it over.  Certainly you cannot sell it of give it to another party.

I would not give the code to them based on weak severance. It is easily worth like 1 year severance to them but what if they come at you rather than pay?  It is clearly a poorly run company - I would not count on rational decisions.

Comment: +1 for: "I would not count on rational decisions". Even if you ponder over your actions and take the most rational choice, don't expect your managers to behave rationally in a situation like that.

Comment: Can I quote you on this? "*Make you come to work with logon privileges - that is just STUPID *".

Answer (score 11):

My advice would be to stay out of this and don't get involved in any way. It's highly unlikely that you'd be able to get any form of reward (extended job, bonus, etc.) if you hand over the files you have.

In addition to that, the managers who were responsible for keeping backups (or for the people whose job was to make backups) will most certainly look for a scapegoat to save themselves. If you show up with the files, you can easily be made into that scapegoat - you really have no way to prove that you didn't cause the sabotage if the network records are as skimpy as you say.

In your situation, I'd delete the files, work off the last 6 weeks and look for another job in the meantime. You cannot (and shouldn't even try) sell the code to someone else - that would be illegal and unethical.

One could argue that it's unethical to not to hand over the files. I agree with that statement but if you go the ethical route, there's nothing that will protect you from the company if one or more managers decide to blame you. The company will have the resources for a long legal battle that you may or may not win at the end. You'll surely lose a lot of money in the meantime, though, if this scenario becomes real.

Comment: There was a nice story on theregister.com where an employee together with his manager set up an excellent new communications system, the manager rented a very expensive temporary internet connection with the intent of cancelling it within 14 days and replacing it with something an awful lot cheaper. With the communications system set up, they were both fired and actually escorted off the premises - job done, not needed anymore. Two months later the company was hit with a six digit communications bill.

Comment: @gnasher729 You have a link to this story? I'd like to read it, but can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

Your original question **How can I benefit from a company disaster?** exposes you as dishonest with ulterior motives. It is unethical to prosper personally during a company disaster such as in this scenario.

Your update makes my point moot, but I will still post this anyway to make my point - **that you should take the high road give the company the code** that you thought you had (which now you know you did not).

As suggested by option number 1 in @AndreiRom [answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/63019/30062) and by option 2 in @Kilsi [answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/63022/30062), you should be honest in this situation. Your company owns the code and until the last day at the time you walk out the door, **you have a duty to act in the best interest of your employer.**

Some of the other answers suggest that by giving them the code, you open yourself to liability. If the company were to come after you, this would be an irrational decision on their part. **The company has an interest in surviving.** The OP by providing the company with the original unmodified code, has done a huge favor for his employer. For the company to take legal action against the OP, they would only be harming themselves. Without the OP's help, **the company would most likely fail sooner or later.**

If I was the owner of the company, and someone sabotaged the code base , I **would gracefully take any help I can** in restoring business operations and would recognize **by cooperating with the OP, I am ensuring my own survival.**

Answer (score 1):

The legal route is simple: you are still paid, and in those 6 weeks must act in the company interest. I don't need to tell you what that route is, do I?

Comment: He wasn't being paid for the work at home.  I see no obligation to save them any heartache.

Comment: @RichardU: Payment is irrelevant. Two reasons. 1, it it wasn't considered a work situation, access to the work servers would not have been authorized, and 2. regardless of how those files were obtained, you now have them while you are being employed.

Comment: Bad faith does not deserve to be rewarded.  I don't  think he should use it to his advantage, but he is in no way required to volunteer the information.  All he has to do is perform his regular job duties to be squeaky clean.

Comment: Another point.  If he turns anything over, aren't they going to assume he was the one who did the damage to begin with?

Comment: It's not so simple.  The company might very well believe the OP was the vandal and pursue legal remedy for damages caused so far.  Getting involved at any level at this point could seriously back fire.

Comment: This answer is not useful.

Comment: I've never seen a clause in a work contract saying you must act in the company's interest.

Comment: @dan-klasson: my current contract says "To carry out all duties diligently and in good faith, and to act in and promote the best interests of the Company". I don't believe they could enforce that clause in cases where my own *legitimate* interest opposes that of the company (for example it doesn't mean I can't pursue a grievance that it would be in the interests of the company for me to just drop). So I think this answer skips considering the factors to be balanced. But the questioner should certainly check for himself what's in his contract rather than relying on the internet to guess :-)

Comment: It's often not in contracts, because  "getting paid to work for the benefit of the company" is either in the law or an accepted common law principle.

Comment: @MSalters Does OP need to decide himself whether to advice CEO on IPO strategy? Or whether to do some plumbing for company toilet? Or should he decide himself whether his daily tasks are a benefit to company or maybe not? No. That's because he is not obliged to "work for the benefit of the company". He's obliged to do his precisely defined duties and to communicate with management about these duties.  That's all. Even a slave or a servant has less obligations than you assert for an employee.

Answer (score -5):

My kudos to the developer who made those changes to the crucial 40,000 lines of source code.The managers  and executives of your company deserve that and worse.

My advice to you - keep quiet about the good source code you have. Your bosses are definitely going to suspect that it was you who intentionally changed the code to benefit from the situation and put you in a lot of legal trouble. You are under no obligation to help your company; let the managers and executives broil in their own juices.

Erase irrecoverably any copies you have of the good source code from before these changes were done from your personal devices (devices that you own, not company's devices). Destroy any thumb drives and preferably even hard disks that you own where you saved the good source code. This is in case your bosses decide to go to court for any reason and have all the computers of all developers, including their petsonal computers, sub poenad and searched for evidence to find out who did this. If you do not wish to destroy hard drives that you own, at least delete the good source code using one of those file shredding applications that make multiple passes and overwrite a file with bit patterns to make them even more difficult to recover or detect they once existed.

Comment: And if it is found out that you did this you will be sued for damages to the company. This is absolutely horrible advice.

Comment: Seconding this.  Given a subpoena and forensic computer people, could they spot mass scrubbing?  If so, the OP looks extremely suspicious.